# Android in-app billing - how does the market notify if a payment fails

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-purchase

I was implementing in-app billing and did not find documentation for the case where if the credit card that the user has configured with the market fails due to a reason say expired date/the user has maxed his card how does the market API notify our app of the failed transaction.

What is the standard practice in such cases.

Following scenario describes it better:
Imagine a user opens the app, taps on an item to buy and then clicks on the accept and buy button on the checkout UI. Now if the credit card associated with google play account of the user is expired, how will my app be notified?

Answer (score 1):

It won't get notified. Payments are handled by the Google Play Store client, and if card verification, etc. fails it will show an error message. If you back off and return to the app (i.e., your app) you will get a generic 'purchase failed', etc. error.

Comment: Thanx for the response. According to you when i press "Accept and buy" in the checkout UI the Google play app will handle all the messaging. What if the processing of the payment takes a bit longer and the checkout UI is dismissed (which according to Google's documentation happens after 60 seconds) what message am I supposed to show to the user. In such cases how do i detect a difference between purchase failure due to credit card issues or due to some other issue. Wont it be a little confusing for the user. Is there a standard way of handling this or some way that you might have used earlier?

Comment: You will get either `RESULT_USER_CANCELED` or `RESULT_ERROR`. The Google Play UI will show a more detailed message, if one is available, and your code doesn't really need to care what exactly went wrong.